# Java android две строки и вторая не отображается

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

У меня такая проблема: есть две строки

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#a1a1a1"
    android:text="Главная"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/main1" />
```

И вторая строка у меня не отображается в приложении.

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: В коде приведённом проблем не видно. Причин может быть несколько десятков. Например у вас строка main1 в ресурсах пустая. Или одно TextView перекрывает другое. Или цвет текста совпадает с фоном. Или вы программно текст сбрасываете. Или программно вьюху убираете. Или не ту разметку смотрите/показываете. etc. Добавьте больше деталей, кода.

Comment: Первый текст я написал в самом layout, а второй у меня находиться в файле res/values/strings.xml. Изначально они показывались оба, только в одной строке словно в таблице и выводились по центру экрана

Comment: @АлексейВакуленко добавьте пожалуйста полный текст XML разметки. Как уже верно заметили, вариантов тут масса. Подозреваю, что первый TextView может не оставлять места второму, как может быть в горизонтальном LinearLayout.

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#a1a1a1"
  android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#e1e1e1"
  android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Как верно выше заметили у вас, кажется (кажется, т.к. код в комментах плохо читается, лучше его в вопрос поместить - там и смотреть лучше и форматирование сохранится) просто одна вьюха другую выталкивает за пределы экрана. Попробуйте всем TextVuew ширину `wrap_content` поставить для начала. Или сделать LinearLayout вертикальным `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в `LinearLayout` не указана ориентация. Она может быть либо `vertical`, либо `horizontal`. Если не указано, по умолчанию используется горизонтальная ориентация.

У первой вьюшки ширина задана как `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, т.е. она занимает всю доступную ширину родительского элемента. Вот и получается, что второй вьюшке просто не остается места, она как бы находится в невидимой правой части экрана.

Можно исправить явно задав ориентацию как вертикальную. Вторая вьюшка в этом случае отобразится ниже первой.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#a1a1a1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e1e1e1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Так же заметил, что в одном из TextView вы используете `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`. Значение `fill_parent` эквивалентно по действию на `match_parent`, но оно устарело уже очень давно, поэтому лучше используйте второй вариант.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за помощь. Да вообще, всем спасибо кто помогал мне в этом вопросе.

Comment: @АлексейВакуленко пожалуйста, я помню себя задавшем примерно такой же вопрос много лет назад :) Если проблема решена, вы можете отменить ответ галочкой (должна быть зеленая рядом со счетчиком), это позволит другим людям легче находить ответы на похожие вопросы.